# The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given

Tags: laravel

Estoy realizando una llamada a un WS en la que la respuesta devuelve un archivo, la respuesta que recibo es la siguiente:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <S:Body>
      <ns0:getDocumentoResponse xmlns:ns0="http://wsdocumentacion/">
         <return>
            <codigoError>0</codigoError>
            <mensajeError xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
            <correcto>S</correcto>
            <datosSalida>
               <array>
                  <nombre>P_CODIGO_PETICION</nombre>
                  <valor>1716104</valor>
               </array>
            </datosSalida>
            <contenidoFichero>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</contenidoFichero>
         </return>
      </ns0:getDocumentoResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Cuando recibo la respuesta me muestra el siguiente error, antes de procesar nada de la respueta:

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
/Users/nando/PhpstormProjects/imediador-web/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php#401
UnexpectedValueException
    public function setContent($content)
    {
        if (null !== $content && !\is_string($content) && !is_numeric($content) && !\is_callable([$content, '__toString'])) {
            throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "%s" given.', \gettype($content)));
        }

        $this->content = (string) $content;
```

No tengo ni idea de como solucionar este error ¿alguna idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Todo se arregló usando un parser para el contenido.
Simplemente tenía que decodificiar la respuesta que obtenía:

```
$base = base64_decode($dataDocument);
```

Y esto ya me genera el documento legible.

Comment: ok.. recuerda aceptar tu respuesta!